# Why won't javascript get by Name?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a group of radio buttons into javascript in order to reset them, however the following code makes `r.length = 0`. Does anyone know if I am able to access radio buttons with getElementByName, and if not, what is the correct way when using a masterpage in asp.net?

**javaScript**

```
        function clearRadios(groupName) {

        var r = document.getElementsByName(groupName);
        for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
              r[i].checked = false;
             }
        }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" runat="server" name="ach_options" id="option1" />

<input type="radio"  runat="server" name="ach_options" id="option2" />

<input type="radio"  runat="server" name="ach_options" id="option3" />
```

**This is how I call the javascript function:**

```
clearRadios("options");
```

FIREFOX Console
[image]

Comment: Exact code is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/tGG8J/ -- Check your console for errors.

Comment: Same here: http://jsfiddle.net/g8Np4/

Comment: What browser are you testing with?

Comment: Are you running the code at the end of the `<body>` or in the `<head>` - run time could be the fault here

Comment: @tymeJV, you need to actually check one, but yes, it works!

Comment: `runat="server"` you say? Are you sure the HTML comes out as intended? Check the resulting source in the browser.

Comment: I added an image. HTML seems correct on browser. No console errors

Comment: You're looking for `"ach_options"` when the name is just `"options"` ..

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I have actually been using ach_options. I copied and pasted incorrectly over here.

Comment: Could it be because I am using asp.net? Since it is working on jsfiddle

Comment: If you're using a web form with a master page, the name of the control does get changed in the resulting HTML. In my test, the result was `<input value="option1" name="ctl00$MainContent$ach_options" type="radio" id="MainContent_option1" />` so maybe you're better off using a class. Or use Kaf's answer.

Comment: @MrLister I ended up using a class like you suggested. (The back-end aspx.cs code.) I can accept if you post an answer in terms of a webpage with a masterpage.

Comment: I can't post another answer to this question, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

It could be due to various reasons, but I would suggest you to wrap radio buttons in a div and use `getElementsByTagName('input')`:

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
   <input type="radio" runat="server" name="ach_options" id="option1" />
   <input type="radio"  runat="server" name="ach_options" id="option2" />
   <input type="radio"  runat="server" name="ach_options" id="option3" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 function clearRadios(wrapperid) {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById(wrapperId);

    //Using getElementsByTagName()
    var r = wrapper.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
          r[i].checked = false;
    }
 }
```

Function call:

```
clearRadios('myDiv');
```